# Float left container hangs in the middle

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I've got the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/69MqZ/1/

As you can see grey text lines up to grey meta data: [image]

I want it to be like this despite length of name to the left: [image]

Obviously it has to use position: relative or some technique that will make border-bottom move accordingly. This is comments output generated by WordPress.

I'm facing the same issue here (all containers have float: left;): 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap a parent element around *both* the comment author name AND the meta data - .comment-author & .comment-meta - and then float THAT parent element. e.g.:

```
 <div class="comment_author_wrap">
 <div class="comment-author vcard">
     <cite class="fn">John Smith</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>        
 </div>

 <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
     <a href="#comment-3">May 23, 2010 at 5:04 pm</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a title="Edit comment" href="3" class="comment-edit-link">(Edit)</a>        
 </div>
 </div>
```

Then

```
.comment_author_wrap {
   float: left;
 }
```

That will allow the comment text to come up all the way to the top of the area like you intend.

Comment: Good solution but I have no impact on WordPress HTML output. Is there any solution to current structure?

Comment: Arg- not any really good ones. The only thing I could think of is position:absolute on the author name and meta info, but that doesn't work if the author name goes longer than one line. I would reconsider the design at this point, if you can't adjust the markup. Even if you float both the author name and meta info separately, the content to the right will only come up as far as the meta info.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I will adjust the HTML markup then somehow. Thank you for taking time to respond! It also resolves my second layout issue where sidebar only goes as far as last blog post :)